# Mootols:How to bind click function to programatically generated elements

Tags: mootools

I have a plain javascript function that generates some links in a page when a button is clicked. Now I want to add a click function for those generated links. I've added a class to each one, but it is still not working. Everything happens in real time and the following mooTools script doesn't work, although it loads in the page just fine.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $$('.jTrigger').addEvent('click', function(){alert('clicked!');})
    })
```

I am looking for the jQuery equivalent of

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".myClass").live("click", function()
{
  do stuff here...
};
});
```

I would use Closure or jQuery(stuff i do know how to use), but I'm working on a Joomla back-end plugin and I was told to stick to MooTools.

Answer (score 1):

MooTools supports [event delegation](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Delegation) too. Here's the example from the docs:

```
// Adding the event, notice the :relay syntax with the selector that matches the target element inside of myElement.
// Every click on an anchor-tag inside of myElement executes this function.
myElement.addEvent('click:relay(a)', function(event, target){
    event.preventDefault();
    request.send({
        url: target.get('href')
    });
});
```

So at a guess (I've never used MooTools), I'd say that if you've added the class `myClass` to the elements in question:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $(document).addEvent('click:relay(.myClass)', function() {
        // One of the elements was clicked
    });
});
```

---

If you're using an older version of MooTools that doesn't have any support for event delegation, it's not a problem, you can do it yourself. Basically, you hook the event on the container (could be `document.body`, but again if possible do it closer to where you're adding the elements), and then when the event is raised, look at `event.target`, which will tell you the actual element the event occurred on. Starting with `event.target`, check each parent to see if it has `myClass`. If so, process the event. So roughly:

```
$(container).addEvent('click', function(event) {
    var match, elm;
    for (elm = event.target; !match && elm; elm = elm.parentNode) {
        if ($(elm).hasClass("myClass")) {
           match = elm;
        }
    }
    if (match) {
        // Yup, its a "myClass" element -- process the click
    }
});
```

Comment: There are probably some syntax differences there...still not working sadly.

Comment: this is the correct syntax given the latest version of mootools. oldr versions need event delegation from mootools-more for this to work. still, i would not recommend adding to document - add to document.body instead.

Comment: @AlexFl: As @Dimitar says, probably don't add to `document` or ideally even to `document.body`; instead, choose the deepest container all of the elements will be within. Event delegation should generally be done as close to the elements as possible (but far enough away to serve its purpose).

Comment: yeah document.body is really not very performant either but it mirrors the .live implementation (which is being deprecated as far as i know). this is all but an example of the equivalent api :)

Comment: @DimitarChristoff: Yes, `live` is deprecated for several reasons. But note that `live` uses `document`, not `document.body`. The current version of `live` is this: `jQuery( this.context ).on( types, this.selector, data, fn );` and `this.context` is, by default, `document` (you can see this in `jQuery.fn.init`). But this is all by-the-bye, event delegation that high is just not a good idea when it can be avoided. :-)

Comment: yep. anyway, he's using joomla - hence it's unlikely the latest mootools and event delegation may not be included in his mootools-more.

Comment: @Alex: I've updated the answer to show how you can do this yourself, if your copy of MooTools doesn't have event delegation built in.

Answer (score 0):

When your code is executed the link arn not in place and then the addEvent will not spice them up. You can verify this assertion with a simple console.log (with firebug on ff at least)

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
     console.log($$('.jTrigger');
     $$('.jTrigger').addEvent('click', function(){alert('clicked!');})
})
```

You have two choice:

- add the behavior to every link everytime it is created (a bit clumsy to me)
- choose a Dom element (the smallest element containing them) and apply an event manager in relay to it:

  window.addEvent('domready', function() {
       document.id(document.body).addEvent('click:relay(a.jTrigger)', function(){alert('clicked!');});
  })

In the example above, I have applied the behaviour to the html body as I don't know anything of your page and the body element will surely contains your links. You need
to apply this behaviour to a smaller subset (minimizing performance issue, as in the documentation is clearly reported).

> In general it is always better to delegate to the closest parent to 
>   your elements as possible; delegate to an element in the page rather 
>   than the document body for example.

Reference: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Delegation

Comment: The immediate parent of those generated elements is the body itself, however it is still not working for some reason... I understand your point however I lack MooTools knowledge

Comment: Okay I think the reason why it wasn't working is because TinyMCE, the crappy joomla editor overrides all other events. The same code on a test page outside Joomla works like a charm. And I am running MooTools 1.4.5 both in Joomla and the test page..